# JS quiz: Help on randomizing answer options & answer button

Tags: javascript, api

Been trying to figure this out for a long time no luck. Your help will be appreciated! Creating a JS quiz using an API!

(1) I am trying to insert the answer options randomly (so for each question, the options are in a different order).

(2) I'm also trying to create a button to reveal answers. I have tried to do it but it's showing all the answer for every question.

```js
let apiUrl = " https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50";

let questions = [];
let questionIndex = 0;

axios.get(apiUrl).then(showQuestion);

//created a function to (1) recieve API information (2) Include info in HTml (3) Make answer options random

function showQuestion(response) {
  let questions = response.data.results;
  console.log(questions);
  console.log(questions[questionIndex]);

  console.log(questions[questionIndex].question);
  let questionPART = document.querySelector("#question");
  questionPART.innerHTML = questions[questionIndex].question;
  let categoryPart = document.querySelector("#category");
  categoryPart.innerHTML = questions[questionIndex].category;

  let correctAnswer = questions[questionIndex].correct_answer;
  let questionInfo = questions[questionIndex].incorrect_answers;
  console.log(correctAnswer);
  console.log(questionInfo);

  //let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionInfo.length);
  //let answerOne = questionInfo[rand];
  //console.log(answerOne);

  function checkAnswer() {
    alert(correctAnswer);
  }

  let answer = document.getElementById("answerButton");
  answer.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);
}

function nextQuestion() {
  axios.get(apiUrl).then(showQuestion);
}

let next = document.getElementById("next");
next.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="quiz" class="quiz">
      <div class="title">Quiz</div>
      <h3 id="category"></h3>
      <h2>
        Question:
        <div class="question" id="question"></div>
      </h2>
      <div class="answer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="flexRadioDefault"
                id="firstButton"
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label labl"
                for="flexRadioDefault2"
                id="firstAnswer"
              >
                Answer 1</label
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="flexRadioDefault"
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label"
                for="flexRadioDefault2"
                id="secondAnswer"
              >
                Answer 1</label
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="flexRadioDefault"
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label"
                for="flexRadioDefault2"
                id="correctAnswer"
              >
                Answer 1</label
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="flexRadioDefault"
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label"
                for="flexRadioDefault2"
                id="thirdAnswer"
              >
                Answer 1</label
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span><button id="next">Next</button></span>
      <button id="answerButton">Answer</button>
```

Comment: You doesn't define the `axios`...

Comment: among other things, you can't use the same IDs for multiple elements. IDs are always unique. To get better help you should consider supplying the data you get back from your ajax call and make it part of your testable snippet

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by supply the data?

Answer (score 0):

1. The API Url contains a space at the beginning which can cause problems.
2. You didn't import Axios.
3. You don't call the showQuestions functions inside the then statement. This would be the solution:

```js
axios.get(apiUrl).then(res => showQuestion(res));
```

4. You need to call the function like this: function(), else you just pass the function